# PHP in a smarty tpl file $_POST doesnt work

Tags: php, smarty

in my where i use smarty to connect everything tpl file i have a form

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group"><label for="address"><strong>Address</strong></label><input class="border rounded-pill form-control" type="text" value='{$address}' name="address"></div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group"><label for="city"><strong>City</strong></label><input class="border rounded-pill form-control" type="text" value='{$city}' name="city"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group"><label for="country"><strong>Country</strong></label><input class="border rounded-pill form-control" type="text" value='{$country}' placeholder="The Netherlands" name="country"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"><label for="phonenumber"><strong>Phone Number</strong></label><input class="border rounded-pill form-control" type="text" value='{$phone}' placeholder="+1 (0)1 234 56 789" name="phonenumber"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="background: #f5f5f5;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="contactsend">Save&nbsp;Settings</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But if i try to contact it in my php file

```
if(isset($_POST['contactsend'])) {
  $inaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
  $incity = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['city']);
  $insert = $db->query("UPDATE accounts SET address = ".$inaddress.", city = ". $incity ." WHERE id = ".$id_user."");
}
```

it wont get the **contactsend** button if i press it, so it also wont update the tables. can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

that form is posting to it's own page ... is the php script in the same file as the render script?  If not you need to set the action="" attribute of the form to the php script url

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem because in other forms where i also didn't use the action=' it also did work but for some reason this one doesn't

Comment: try var_dump($_POST); before the if statement to see what is in there and it's state

Comment: $_POST['contactsend'] is a button so there aint no varchar in the $_POST